# Using LiveValidation in HTML/PHP project

Tags: php, html, validation, client-side

I've found following javascript library for client-side validation:

http://livevalidation.com/

The examples on the website are very clear, but I just can't get them to work...

Even when creating a very basic html-only website like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="scrip" type="text/javascript" href="scripts/LiveValidation-1.3.js" title="LiveValidation"/>
</head>

Enter the field then click somewhere else:
    <input type="text" id="f1"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f1 = new LiveValidation('f1');
        f1.add(Validate.Presence);
    </script>

</html>
```

This code comes directly from the examples provided on the website, however it doesn't do anything, the reference to the .js file is correct... What am I overlooking here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a script tag to reference the javascript file not the link tag.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/LiveValidation-1.3.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Oh God, it's just that? :p Thanks